# Review website for research groups

Tags: phd, ethics, advisor, professorship, supervision

I was wondering if there is a website that allows you to rate research groups/professors that you've worked for. I know about '[http://www.ratemyprofessors.com](http://www.ratemyprofessors.com/)', but I was thinking about a website specifically for academic reviews, and this example is more or less limited to lectures.

If my research is correct, there's currently no such options, it sounds like an idea to implement something similar. What do you guys think? Would you be interested in using something like this?

The goal of the project would be creating transparency in science, and the build could be similar to [glassdoor](https://www.glassdoor.co.uk/index.htm?countryRedirect=true). There are for sure some concerns about the sample size and anonymity, especially in the case of smaller research groups, but it might still be better than nothing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a "Rate my Advisor" type website?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/76111/is-there-a-rate-my-advisor-type-website)

Answer (score 2):

There are unfortunately numerous issues that I see with this.

1. Many research groups are small enough that anonymity would be next to impossible.
2. Similarly, most professors only advise a few students at a time and it would take forever to build up any sort of meaningful amount of reviews on any one professor.
3. Most research groups are transient. As students graduate, the group will be changing on what is likely a yearly basis. Just because Jim and Jill were great to work with in the Bonsti Lab three years ago does not mean that Jim and Jill will still be there now.
4. RateMyProfessor is somewhat of a cesspool at times. It can certainly show overall trends (such as 23 reviews that mention that the professor cannot write a clear test or 19 reviews that all mention how messy a professor is), but such trends would be too subtle to notice over just a few students.

One is likely best served by just speaking to current graduate students in the lab of one's interest. Students usually know if there is an overall troublesome situation in a given lab.