# Postdoc experience sharing platform

Tags: postdocs, lab-management

I was wondering if there is a website or forum where postdocs can post their experiences and honest opinions of their research labs...anonymously. I have a feeling that many postdocs go to a lab only to find it's nothing like what it was said to be (by the PI or staff that the PI chose to contact you) and then get stuck. And on the other hand searching for lab members from that lab can be tricky because they either don't want to answer because they are afraid to say anything bad or the PI doesn't allow them to respond and/or does not want future postdocs communicating with ones already in the lab.

Comment: This is a shopping question.

Comment: Related: [Is there a "Rate my Advisor" type website?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/76111/17254), [Review website for research groups](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/119358/17254)